# How to delete a record from production in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On the odd occasion, I need to delete a record from the production database, but I don't keep a `Destroy` link in the view.  So at the moment, I'm just adding:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', coffeeshop_path(@coffeeshop),
              method: :delete,
              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

and pushing it live when I need it.  This is far from ideal. Is there another way to do this such as when we append the url with `new` or `edit`. I tried adding `destroy` or even `delete` but this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to hit the url with `:delete` method

Comment: why don't just provide this url to Admin account

Comment: Since the occasion is odd, I would prefer console is such scenario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below steps to delete record from production database:

1. `ssh` on server
2. Goto the directory of your app
3. Run command:

   RAILS_ENV=production rails console
4. Find the record:

   c = Coffeeshop.find(id)

   c.delete

Answer (score 1):

If you ssh into the server, you can use `bundle exec rails console production`  and delete the record that way.