# Delete records from heroku production in phoenix app

Tags: heroku, phoenix-framework

Similar to this question I asked on how to delete live records in a rails app, how do I do this in Phoenix [How to delete a record from production in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517275/how-to-delete-a-record-from-production-in-rails)

I tried `heroku run iex -S mix phx.server` but I got the bellow error:

```
Simons-MBP:iotc Simon$ heroku run iex -S mix phx.server
Running iex -S mix phx.server on ⬢ icingonthecake... up, run.3732 (Free)
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

14:29:43.723 [info] Running Iotc.Web.Endpoint with Cowboy using http://:::54253
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.276.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.282.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.287.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.281.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.284.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.279.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
14:29:43.734 [error] Postgrex.Protocol (#PID<0.286.0>) failed to connect: ** (Postgrex.Error) FATAL 53300 (too_many_connections): too many connections for role "onktihhpdhhwlp"
```

Comment: That sounds like some Heroku Database connection limit you're hitting. Phoenix creates a pool of connections and you probably have the application running as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a `pool_size` problem in the `apps/<yourapp>/config/*.exs` files -- if you're using Phoenix 1.3 that is (not sure where the configs are in 1.2 or below). I've had it set to 60 on my local machine and I wasn't even able to execute any mix task if I already had a console running. I dropped my `pool_size` to 10 and was fine.

Reference: https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/issues/210#issuecomment-239941678